# test for errors in ruby watir script

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have several ruby watir-webdriver scripts I am using to automate downloading files from various websites.  simple scripts that log in to site, fill in text fields, click buttons.....  what do I have to do to get the script to send an email alert any time there is an error or timeout?  Scripts are running on a Mac OSX server and I can use /usr/bin/mail.

just looking to get a simple error message if the script stops before the last line of the script which is:

```
b.close
```

Thanks for all of your help

Comment: Look to your test framework to handle that stuff and move on to the next test. In RSpec, it would be an after :each. There are similar in test::unit and maybe even cucumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not elegant, but the simplest way to do this would be to use a begin/rescue/end block.

```
begin
   <actionable code here>
rescue => e
   puts "Error: #{e}"
end

b.close
```

You can update the "puts" section to instead email or write the error to a text file.

Comment: Awesome,  Thanks Adam!!!!  Just recently switched from perl-LWP to ruby and watir.  Bit of a learning curve but far more robust the LWP or Mech.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [mail gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mail) if you need to send mail.